# ProtoBuf-Linq error message “ Invalid field in source data: 0”

Tags: linq, protobuf-net

I've encountered the following issue while using protobuf-linq:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    SerializeMultiple(PrepareData(), stream);
}

private static void SerializeMultiple(IEnumerable<Person> persons, Stream stream)
{            
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, person);
    }

    stream.Position = 0;

    var q = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.AsQueryable<Person>(stream,null);
    var results = from e in q
                  where e.Id % 2 == 0
                  select new { e.Id, e.Name };

    Console.WriteLine("first : " + results.First().Id);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static IEnumerable<Person> PrepareData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) 1e+04; i++)
    {
        yield return new Person {Id = i, Name= "John" + i, Address = "Address" + i*i};
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
class Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

The `AsQueryable` line throws the aforementioned exception:

> Invalid field in source data: 0

Any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: I suspect this is a question for Scooletz (protobuf-linq author); I have pinged them via NuGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not protobuf-linq error. When serializing items into a stream, you should use SerializeWithLengthPrefix to prefix every message with its length, to allow separate them. By default, protobuf-linq uses PrefixStyle.Base128. Below you can find a snippet making it right:

```
      Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, person, PrefixStyle.Base128);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Scooletz. Additionally could you tell when it's appropriate to use .AsQueryable() over DeserializeItems()

Comment: @GenaVerdel Do you mean when to use protobuf-linq and when to use standard deserialization? If so, use protobuf-linq if you project only a subset of properties, like in your case - Address is skipped. The more skipped properties, the faster query will be. Hope that helps.